# Make a range in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, range, intervals

How can I make a range in a select in PostgreSQL? I'd like to have this result:

```
num
---
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

From a query like:

```
SELECT range(1,6) AS num;
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    generate_series(1, 6) num
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html